# SharePoint 2010 list Item Query

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, sharepoint-server, javascript, caml

We have a big list in SharePoint 2010. I'm gonna query SharePoint 2010 list item in the web part based on country. I used CAML and JS. I have got errors in different browser"

Internet explorer says

> "Object doesn't support property or method 'getElementsByTagNameNS'"

chrome says

> "500 (Internal Server Error)".

**Here is my Code:**

```
<input type="text" style="width:350px" id="txtSearch" />
<input type="button" style=" font-size:15px;font-family:'Segoe UI 
Light','Segoe UI','Segoe',Tahoma,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; background-
color:#0072C6; color:white" id="btnSearch" value="Search" onclick="return 
search(); return false" />
 <style>
.highlight {
background-color: #FFFF88;
}
</style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://.../SiteAssets/jquery-
1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

/*
 *This is jQuery Highlight plugin to highlight the result text

 */

jQuery.extend({
highlight: function (node, re, nodeName, className) {
    if (node.nodeType === 3) {
        var match = node.data.match(re);
        if (match) {
            var highlight = document.createElement(nodeName || 'span');
            highlight.className = className || 'highlight';
            var wordNode = node.splitText(match.index);
            wordNode.splitText(match[0].length);
            var wordClone = wordNode.cloneNode(true);
            highlight.appendChild(wordClone);
            wordNode.parentNode.replaceChild(highlight, wordNode);
            return 1; //skip added node in parent
        }
    } else if ((node.nodeType === 1 && node.childNodes) && // only element 
nodes that have children
            !/(script|style)/i.test(node.tagName) && // ignore script and 
style nodes
            !(node.tagName === nodeName.toUpperCase() && node.className === 
className)) { // skip if already highlighted
        for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++) {
            i += jQuery.highlight(node.childNodes[i], re, nodeName, 
className);
        }
    }
    return 0;
    }
});

jQuery.fn.unhighlight = function (options) {
var settings = { className: 'highlight', element: 'span' };
jQuery.extend(settings, options);

return this.find(settings.element + "." + settings.className).each(function 
() {
    var parent = this.parentNode;
    parent.replaceChild(this.firstChild, this);
    parent.normalize();
}).end();
};

jQuery.fn.highlight = function (words, options) {
var settings = { className: 'highlight', element: 'span', caseSensitive: 
false, wordsOnly: false };
jQuery.extend(settings, options);

if (words.constructor === String) {
    words = [words];
}
words = jQuery.grep(words, function(word, i){
  return word != '';
});
words = jQuery.map(words, function(word, i) {
  return word.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&");
});
if (words.length == 0) { return this; };

var flag = settings.caseSensitive ? "" : "i";
var pattern = "(" + words.join("|") + ")";
if (settings.wordsOnly) {
    pattern = "\\b" + pattern + "\\b";
}
var re = new RegExp(pattern, flag);

return this.each(function () {
    jQuery.highlight(this, re, settings.element, settings.className);
});
};

</script>
<select id="CountryChoice">
<option selected value="Select" >Select</option>
<option value="Global/Other" >Global/Other</option>
<option value="A">A</option>
<option value="B" >B</option>
<option value="C">C</option>
<option value="D" >D</option>
<option value="E">E</option>
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">

        function search()

      {
      var Countryqry= document.getElementById("CountryChoice").value;
       $("#tasksUL").empty();
      var qry= document.getElementById("txtSearch").value
  var soapEnv =
        "<soapenv:Envelope 
xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'> \
            <soapenv:Body> \
                 <GetListItems 
xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'> \
                    <listName>Project Inventory</listName> \
                    <viewFields> \
                        <ViewFields> \
                 <FieldRef Name='Title' /> \
                <FieldRef Name='ID' /> \
                <FieldRef Name='Modified' /> \
                <FieldRef Name='Last Name' /> \
                <FieldRef Name='First Name' /> \
                <FieldRef Name='Age' /> \
                <FieldRef Name='Country' /> \
                       </ViewFields> \
      </viewFields> \
      <query> \
      <Query> \
 <Where> \
<And> \
     <Eq> \
        <FieldRef Name='Country' /> \
         <Value Type='Choice'>"+Countryqry+"</Value> \
     </Eq> \
<Or> \
<Contains> \
     <FieldRef Name='Title' /> \
     <Value Type='Text'>"+qry+"</Value> \
</Contains> \
<Or> \
<Contains> \
     <FieldRef Name='LastName' /> \
     <Value Type='Text'>"+qry+"</Value> \
</Contains> \
<Or> \
<Contains> \
     <FieldRef Name='First Name' /> \
     <Value Type='Text'>"+qry+"</Value> \
  </Contains> \
           <Contains> \
           <FieldRef Name='Age' /> \
              <Value Type='Text'>"+qry+"</Value> \
              </Contains> \
        </Or> \
     </Or> \
  </Or> \
  </And> \
  </Where> \
</Query> \
  </query> \
   </GetListItems> \
            </soapenv:Body> \
        </soapenv:Envelope>";       

    $.ajax({
        url: "https://.../sb1/_vti_bin/lists.asmx",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "xml",
        data: soapEnv,
        complete: processResult,
        contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""
        });

 }

    function processResult(xData, status) {
// show searching text and image when search button is clicked
var loadhtml="<div id='loading' class='ms-dlgLoadingTextDiv'><span 
style='padding-top: 6px; padding-right: 10px;'><img width='24' height='24' 
title='This animation indicates the operation is in progress. Click to 
remove this animated image.' src='/_layouts/15/images/gears_anv4.gif?
rev=36'/></span><span class='ms-core-pageTitle ms-accentText'>Searching...
</span></div>";

//var totalRows = $(xData.responseXML).find("rs\\:data").attr("ItemCount");
var totalRows =   getZRows(xData.responseXML);
if(totalRows=="0")
{
 $("#loading").remove();
$("#tasksUL").before("<div  id='loading'  style='color:red;font-
size:15px'>No matching records found. Please refine your search.</div>");
return true;
}
$("#tasksUL").before(loadhtml);
    $(xData.responseXML).find("z\\:row, row").each(function() {
F
// creating hyperlink for each item to display form of that list item
var lnk="<a href='https://ABC/Lists/Project%20Inventory/DispForm.aspx?ID=" + 
$(this).attr('ows_ID') + "&source=https://ABC/SitePages/Home.aspx'>"+ 
$(this).attr("ows_Title") +"</a>";

        var liHtml = "<li>"+ lnk+"</li>";

// 2 second delay and show searching text and image also highlight the 
result with the searched keyword
setTimeout(function(){
 $("#loading").remove();
   $("#tasksUL").append(liHtml);
  $("#tasksUL > li").highlight(document.getElementById("txtSearch").value);
}, 2000);

        });

    }


$(document).ready(function(){
// check if enter button is pressed and then search button clicked event is 
called
    $('#txtSearch').keypress(function(e){
      if(e.keyCode==13)
     { $('#btnSearch').click();return false;}
    });
});

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function getZRows(rXML) {
  var rows;
  var itemCount = $(rXML).find("rs\\:data").attr("ItemCount");
 if (rXML.getElementsByTagName("z:row").length == 0 && itemCount == 
undefined) {
   rows = rXML.getElementsByTagNameNS("*", "row");
  } else {
  rows = rXML.getElementsByTagName("z:row");
  }
  return rows.length;
 }
</script>

<div id="search_result">
<ul id="tasksUL"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you independently tested your viewFields and your Query? http://www.camldesigner.com/index.php/2016/01/12/caml-designer-2013/ is the tool that I have used with great success. I would be suspect of your viewFields selection first. Also, you may need to filter in both caml and js because you might find that csom filters do not give you all the tools you need.

Comment: Can you also add your response XML?

Answer (score 0):

The code is almost correct. Probably the internal server error is due to wrong internal names of the fields: "Last Name" and "First Name".

This is because you have to use the internal names of the fields in the caml query. Is sure that the internal names does not contains spaces.
You can obtain the correct internal names looking into the Edit field page:
`/_layouts/15/FldEdit.aspx?List=%7BB79DFB83-378A-4D3B-BC21-BD808E6F2EF8%7D&Field=First_x0020_Name`

Usually is First_x0020_Name or FirstName.