# Query list item from top level site

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, caml-query

Correction of my previous question:[Link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/217039/sharepoint-2010-list-item-query)

I have big list in my sub-site. I want to query a list item from a top level site. I can able to query from a sub-site , but my requirement is users want to query from the top level site ?